# Why are latching relays so popular in oscilloscope front-ends?

Tags: latching-relay

I've seen many latching relays used in oscilloscope front-ends, particularly the input attenuator section. Beside the merit of 'energy-saving' of a latching relay, are there any other advantages?

And what about its usage in harsh industrial environment, such as high magnetic interference?

Comment: Have you got a snippet of a schematic of a latching relay used in an o-scope front end? For your 2nd question, are you asking about whether latching relays are suitable for environments having high magnetic fields?

Comment: Sorry, I have no pics for now. But, I'm sure B3GB4.5Z is used in Rigol and Pico's oscilloscopes (at least some products, if not all). And other latching relay models from various vendors in some DAQ cards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Latching relays have the advantage that a powered-up scope immediately has the expected gain range setting, even if the computer parts haven't awakened.   Relays are less  intrusive on a signal than most solid-state devices would be (they take high voltages and currents, and have low resistance and inductance).

As for 'harsh' environments, a latching relay is retained by a small permanent magnet: any environment that could dominate that permanent magnet would also ruin transformer, motor, and inductor devices of
other sorts.   The oscilloscope's switchmode power would fail,
and pacemakers could malfunction.   Industrial safety doesn't
allow for that much stray magnetic field.

Comment: I think non-latching relay may have a more 'reliable' state when powered-up. The NC or NO contact will retained their state even not energied. But for latching relay, they may change state after shock, right?

Comment: @diverger - A double-throw latching relay has a complete magnetic circuit in both states, and (because magnetic force is very high over short gaps) that's optimal for state retention.   A non-latching relay has a spring holding the contact in one state, and a magnetic circuit (opposed by the spring) in the other.   Either can be dislodged by enough shock, but the latching relay isn't especially at a disadvantage.

Answer (score 4):

with no constant power demand they don't heat up, this reduces thermocouple voltage, also means there's no electromagnet spewing out PSU voltage ripple as magnetic waves, also means a smaller PSU can be used as the relays can be powered in sequence instead of requiring simultaneous power.